# MXToolbox: "Reverse DNS is not a valid Hostname"

Tags: email-server, reverse-dns

I know that there is another thread about this topic here on serverfault.com but it did not solve my issue.

I have also googled it and it seems that SPF record could be mis-configured in some cases but it did not help me neither.

Can someone tell please me why I am getting the "Reverse DNS is not a valid Hostname" error:
http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3awebkonsulenter.dk&run=toolpage#

Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Maybe MX Toolbox is having a problem.

Comment: Same here, everything looks OK, your MX record:  `webkonsulenter.dk.      3600    IN      MX      10 mail-hosting.dk.`  , the A record for MX host:
`mail-hosting.dk.        3598    IN      A       85.114.139.44`  and the reverse lookup: 
`44.139.114.85.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN    PTR     mail-hosting.dk.`

Comment: Thank you both :-) I have contacted MXToolBox Support in order to cast some light over the issue :-)

Comment: Might it be because it's not a host name, but a domain name instead? I mean, server name should be something like mgw.mail-hosting.dk . You're  using the domain name instead.

Answer (score 12):

Response from MXToolBox Support:

> Your PTR record is mail-hosting.dk which is a Domain name. The RFC
>   guidelines say that is must be a hostname such as
>   mail.mail-hosting.dk. Most systems won't care that it is a domain, but
>   since it's against the RFC guidelines, we show a warning.